# Bootstrap 3: URL to auto-open modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I have a page with a Bootstrap 3 modal that's hidden, but I want to know if there is a URL I can use in other places to force the modal to launch automatically when the page loads.

For instance...

**Page URL:** `http://example.com/page`

**Same URL, (but modal auto-launches):** `http://example.com/page#myModal`

Does anyone know if such a thing is possible?

Answer (score 2):

This slightly different snippet worked for me like a charm. It basically checks 
on load whether if the URL contains "#something" at the end. If so, it shows the modal dialog. [Source](https://gist.github.com/MrDys/3512455)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to do like this :

```js
if (window.location.hash && $(window.location.hash).length) {
  $(window.location.hash).modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is definitely possible. I'm not sure if there's a more bootstrap-py way of doing this or not (it's been a while since I've played around with bootstrap), but you should be able to inspect the `window.location.hash` on page load and show the modal if the hash you're looking for is present. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf("myHash") !== -1) {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }
});
```

Where "myHash" is the hash you're looking for and "myModal" is the ID of the modal element you'd like to open.